# Scanner not recognised on Epson Printer after El Capitan update

Tags: macos, printing, scanning

I've noticed that the scanner option has disappeared from the System Preferences (Printers & Scanners) control for the Epson AL CX21NF. I've tried installing the drivers from [here](http://esupport.epson-europe.com/ProductHome.aspx?lng=en-GB&data=0ccCGROWIYNH7KqehDEpZSVlWkwE8WepD2pLxON06HQU003D&tc=6) and also using the System update from Apple (specific to Epson printers via the App Store). I have added the printer (using the IP address and LPD Line Daemon option) and can print to the device, but have no option to scan documents.

Has something changed in El Capitan or is this printer now just too old to be supported?

Comment: Is Preview/File/Import From Scanner active or greyed out?

Comment: Please can you be more specific? Do you mean from the stock Apple Preview application via the file menu? There used to be a scanner button on the printer's preference pane but it is no longer there.

Comment: Yes the stock app.

Comment: It is greyed out in the preview app

Answer (score 2):

El Capitan has problems supporting scanners. After talking to Apple tecs, and Epson techs and getting the run around, my easy fix was to pay for and down load VueScan and my scanner works again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Reset printing system`:

1. Go to  -> `System Preferences`
2. Select `Printers & Scanners`
3. In the left Sidebar (in the white area) do a control-click
4. Choose `Reset printing system`

More informations [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201539)

Comment: This had no effect

Comment: Did you try everything from here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21726?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: yes i did try those - in any case they are not specific to scanning, more general printing troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the universal print driver is just that - a print driver, not a scanner driver. From what it says on the page you linked, the scanner software was last updated in 2009. (I know all-in-ones are popular but I prefer standalone single function devices, as it prevents me from ending up with a unit that is 90% usable and 10% irreparably broken...)